# Add records using HABTM association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I still new with ruby on rails and I am really blocked.
I am trying to add linked books and authors to database, it add the record in the two tables but not in tne join one. This is my code:

books_controller.rb

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController

  def index
   @books= Book.all
  end

  def new
   @book= Book.new
  end

  def create
   @book= Book.new(book_params)
    if @book.save
     redirect_to books_path
    else
     redirect_to root_url
    end

   end


   private
    def book_params
     params.require(:book).permit(:title, {:author_ids =>[]})
    end
   end
```

book.rb

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :authors
  before_destroy { authors.clear }
end
```

author.rb

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :books
end
```

books/new.html.erb

```
<h1>Add new book</h1>
 <%= form_for @book do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%=f.text_field :title %>
      <% for author in Author.all %>
        <%= check_box_tag 'book(author_ids[])',author.id, @book.authors.include?(author) %>
       <%= author.f_name %>
      <% end%>
     <%= f.submit %>
  <%end%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `<%= check_box_tag 'book(author_ids[])',author.id, @book.authors.include?(author) %>` into `<%= check_box_tag 'book[author_ids][]',author.id, @book.authors.include?(author) %>`

Comment: yes! thanks a lot :) Could you please explain to me what's the utility of book[author_ids][] because i just follow a tutorialand i can not understand

Comment: This is the way you define form fields in Rails. I mean having `<%=f.text_field :title %>` defines your field name as `book[title]`. For that field in controller `params[:book][:title] # => returns book title given in form` Now, more complicated case, `book[author_ids][]`. It means that you want to send an array of `ids` to your controller. This is very useful when defining a multi value fields (i.e. book may have many authors). Such definition in view is accessed within your controller by simply `params[:book][:author_ids]` and returns array.